# Firebase authentication in ReactJS project - user null inside onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm tearing my hair out trying to setup email/password authentication through firebase.
I've got my firebase configuration setup like so

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import firebase from "firebase/app";
//authenticaion module
import "firebase/auth";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
 // I've got my api key and other info copied from the console in here
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const db = firebase.firestore();
export const app = firebase.auth();
```

I've got a sign-in form created that calls the following function:

```
import { app } from "../firebase/firebaseConfig";

  const createAccount = () => {
    app
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("user created");
        console.dir(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      });
  };
```

First problem: I'm not seeing the "user created" message, even though I can see the user being created in the Firebase Authentication console. I'm also not seeing the "something went wrong" message that would indicate an exception occurred.

Second problem: I'm trying to do a re-direct when the user signs in. To do this, I've setup a listener on the Firebase auth object as suggested in the docs:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  console.log("Inside listener");
  console.dir(user);
});
```

The problem is, I'm seeing the console message so the function is triggering but 'user' is always null in here even though the user is being created.

Firebase version: 8.2.1

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you double check that `createAccount()` is being called by adding a console.log before app. createUserWithEmailAndPassword statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in case anyone runs into a similar issue - the button that was triggering the submit was inside a html form and I was not calling event.preventDefault() and so the page was re-rendering and I believe this was causing the auth callback to work incorrectly. Working code -

```
  const createAccount = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    app
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("user created");
        console.dir(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that in an auth state listener your callback first gets called with `null`, as that is typically the initial user authentication state as the page is loaded.

Firebase tries to automatically restore the user's authentication state, but this may take some time. Only once the state is restored will it again call your auth state listener with the then active user account.

Comment: That makes sense, but the listener is only ever being called once and the user is null.

Comment: In that case the user is never signed in, which would also explain why you never see the "user created" message of the first snippet. Are any error showing in the dev console of your browser? If not, check the network calls for any hints (although that's uncommon).

Comment: In other terms, `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is not for "sign-in" but for user registration.

Comment: A newly created user is automatically signed in Martin, so success wuold both log "user created" and invoke the auth callback with a user.

Comment: I know, but the text of the question doesn't match it's code too well... therefore I'd suspect some misconception (unless the intention is attempting to add the user over and over again).

Comment: Hey @SabrinaTessier Did you make any progress with this after my last comment?

Comment: Yes, I solved my own issue. It was a  React re-rendering issue caused by me forgetting to add event.prevent default in my submit function for the form. I believe the re-rendering was causing the onAuthStateChange function to work incorrectly and therefore the auth user object was never being set properly. I posted my answer above and marked it correct.

Comment: Ah, I now see it. Perfect! 